# How to define an interface that forces to use the value of another interface?

Tags: typescript

So I have this interface with the keys needed to build a payload request.

```
Interface PayloadKeys {
   Activate: string,
   Multiple: string,
}
```

A use case is setting it like:

```
const payloadKey: PayloadKeys = {
   Activate: 'some_key',
   Multiple: 'some_other_key',
}
```

and using it with:

```
const myRequest = {
   [payloadKey.Activate]: myValue,
   [payloadKey.Multiple]: myOtherValue,
   otherNotDynamicStuff: 'something'
}
```

I am trying to build an interface for `myRequest`, so it forces me to declare `payloadKey.Activate` and `payloadKey.Multiple` but I can not find a way to do it, I can just find the keys with `[K in keyof TableRequestPayloadKeys]` but that does not help me.

Comment: If you wan to use payloadKeys values as a keys in new object see this  `type MyRequest = {  [Prop in keyof PayloadKeys as PayloadKeys[Prop]]: string}`

Comment: I suppose this is as good as It gets, It still gets inferred as `string` but then it is at least documented.

Comment: see this example https://tsplay.dev/NrGyDm

Answer (score 0):

If `Activate` and `Multiple` can be any string at runtime, you can only type them as such, I think:

```
interface MyRequest {
  nonDynamicStuff: string | 'something'
  [dynamicKey: string]: string
}
```

It might be cleaner to include keys `Activate` and `Multiple` in the request and use them wherever the request is accepted instead, if possible.

Comment: Sadly, the backend people can not change that :(

Comment: Is it important which key is Activate and which is Multiple? Or are you just having the backend assign values to arbitrary keys? If the api accepts a payload with any set of key:string, you may simply type the payload as `Record<string, string>`